# SQL - delete record where sum = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table which has below values:
[image]

If Sum of values = 0 with same ID I want to delete them from the table. So result should look like this:
[image]

The code I have:

```
DELETE FROM tmp_table
WHERE ID in 
            (SELECT ID
            FROM tmp_table WITH(NOLOCK) 
            GROUP BY ID
            HAVING SUM(value) = 0)
```

Only deletes rows with ID = 2.

UPD: Including additional example:
Rows in yellow needs to be deleted
[image]

Comment: Please explain what happens if you have 10/10/-10/-10? or 10/10/10/-10/-10?  Your example is not complete.  And provide a database tag.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but just to clarify the question, do you want the query to also delete the first two rows with ID = 1 without deleting the third row with ID = 1?

Comment: @MarkLodato - I think that's what they do want, which is a more complex query

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated my question.

Comment: @MarkLodato yes, I need the query to delete first two rows since sum = 0  and leave third row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want using window functions -- by enumerating the values for each `id`.  Taking your approach using a subquery:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, value order by id) as seqnum
      from tmp_table t
     )
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.value = - t.value and t2.seqnum = t.seqnum
                 );
```

You can also do this with a second layer of window functions:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, value order by id) as seqnum
      from tmp_table t
     ),
     tt as (
      select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id, abs(value), seqnum) as cnt
      from t
     )
delete from tt
    where cnt = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is working correctly because the only group to total zero is `id` 2, the others have sub-groups which total zero (such as the first two with `id` 1) but the total for all those records is -3.

What you're wanting is a much more complex algorithm to do "[bin packing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/bin-packing-problems-the-sql/)" in order to remove the sub groups which sum to zero.

Comment: yes, I am trying to modify it so it returns result that I need, thank you, I will look into it.

Comment: Here's a link to some more search results which may help: [bin packing in sql group](https://www.google.com/search?q=bin+packing+in+sql+group&oq=bin+packing+in+sql+group)

Comment: @Tony . . . This isn't a bin-packing problem.  The OP is looking for exact matches on the negative amounts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Ika didn't explicitly say they only wanted to remove exact opposites, so I assumed the values are random and some _might_ total zero. e.g: 7, 1, -4, -3 would result in just +1 being left. If, however, they only want to remove exact matches the solution is not as complex. Either way I hope Ika has learnt something from exploring the problem :)